# Asynchronous launching and finishing Activites

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-activity, back-stack

OK, here's my case.

I have activities A, B, C, D. They get launched from one another in the order A -> C -> D. B is interchangeable with A (a combination B -> C -> D is equally possible). I also have a service that awaits an event and another activity E. When the event occurs, the intended behavior depends on which activity is in the foreground:

- When A or B is visible or the app is not in the foreground at all, the order of activities on the stack should not change.
- When C is visible, I want to remove C and place E in its place: A -> E or B -> E, respectively.
- When D is visible, I want to remove both C and D and place E in their place: A -> E or B -> E.

More general solutions (handling situations like A -> C1 -> C2 -> ... changed into A -> E) are welcome, as the app is going to be extended in the future and new functionalities are going to be added (their exact shape is not yet determined).

I have bitten through the [Tasks and Back Stacks](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) document at the Android developer site as well as several SO threads on the subject, but couldn't find a nice solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) and add a few methods like:

```
public static MyApplication getInstance() // returns a reference to the application
public void setForegroundActivity(Activity);
public Activity getForegroundActivity(); //
```

Then in your Activities' `onResume()` methods call `setForegroundActivity(this)`, and in `onPause()` call `setForegroundActivity(null)`.

When your asynchronous event is called, you can check the activity returned from `getForegroundActivity()` and determine which one it is. How you determine which activity it is, is up to you (you could check the type of the instance for example).

Comment: So then I know which activity is on top, and I can finish it. In the A -> C -> D case, how do I then get rid of the C activity?

Comment: You could, send a broadcast(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) That contains information on what activities should finish themselves, the interested Activities can then register a receiver for that broadcast Intent.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but there seems to be one problem with the broadcast receiver approach. If I register/unregister the receiver in onResume/onPause or onStart/onStop, then it will get unregistered when another activity hides the one with the receiver. So the activity loses the receiver just when I need it to keep it. On the other hand, if I do the reg/unreg in onCreate/onDestroy, the receiver might leak if the system decides to dispose of the activity due to memory issues. This will give me an exception and kill the app...

Comment: You could declare an intent filter in AndroidManifest